# does raspberry pi 2 support thingsboard IOT platform?

Tags: iot, raspberry-pi2, thingsboard

I want to know whether Raspberry Pi 2 support ThingsBoard platform? Can I just follow the steps of installing ThingsBoard for RPi3 and will it work for RPi2 also?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is supported. based on this link: https://thingsboard.io/docs/samples/raspberry/gpio/ :

```
Raspberry Pi - we will use Raspberry Pi 3 Model B but you can use any other model.
```

Also, support is mainly related to what protocols are available and supported by the platform:

```
https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/protocols/
MQTT
CoAP
HTTP
```

Answer (score 0):

We are currently running ThingsBoard gateway in a Raspberry Pi 2 model B, so I can confirm it is fully supported. Installed following the official guide [here](https://thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/install/rpi/), with Raspbian Stretch Headless as operating system.